# IDL - calculating Median

Tags: plot, histogram, median, idl

How to calculate a median for the histogram below? The "n_p" variable is double and the "np_omni" variable is float. But I am not sure what the "h" variable represents. I am still confused about the data types.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `HISTOGRAM` is an [N]-element array of counts for an [N]-element array of bin locations (i.e., the `LOCATIONS` keyword you used).  If you use the `MEDIAN` function on `h`, the result would be the median of the counts in all these bins, not the median of the `n_p` variable.  To find the median of the `n_p` variable, do the following:

```
npmd = MEDIAN(n_p)
```

(or include the array of indices from `ind` if you only want that subset of values to calculate the median)

The *float* and *double* datatypes refer to single- and double-precision floating point numbers.